# Using dvdrental.tar as a learning tool, my INNER JOIN output is not showing any rows of data

Tags: pgadmin-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61cDk.png)

I am currently using a Macbook Pro with PostgresSQL 16. I am not sure what's causing my Query Output to look like this.

I tried closing the program and opening it again. It is supposed to look like this: